# Javascript Works in Firefox & Chrome but not IE

Tags: javascript

The following page works in Firefox and Chrome but not IE10.

[Example](http://www.curtainsmadesimple.co.uk/214/Prestigious-Textiles/Peony-Gardens-Fabric-Collection)

The JavaScript message is "Unable to get property '1' of undefined or null reference".

It happens when I click on the information icon that exists under each image.

It is breaking on this line...

```
var versNum=parseFloat(agent.match(/MSIE[ ](\d\.\d+)\.*/i)[1])
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you include relevant code in the question.

Comment: Well, the error message is quite descriptive. `agent.match(/MSIE .*/i)` did return `null`, and no property can be accessed on that.

Comment: there is some browser compatability issue in your  application you need to check which javascript tag or selector is not responding in your application while using IE10. Then search the alternative tag for IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your `match` function doesn't find the match of the regular expression it returns `null`. Replace this line with the following:

```
var match = agent.match(/MSIE .*/i);
var versNum = null;
if (null !== match) {
    versNum = parseFloat(match[1]);
}
```

Moreover, I don't know the value of your `agent` variable but if it is raw user agent string then your regular expression won't work either. If you want to fetch the browser version you should use the following regex:

```
var match = agent.match(/MSIE ([^;]*)/i);
```